# MapServer / PostgreSQL don't display an ITEMQUERY

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver, query, ms4w

I try to search a string in MapServer with the method ITEMQUERY from a PostgreSQL table,. It look very simple but I receive the folow error:
msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query: ERROR: el argumento de AND debe ser de tipo boolean, no tipo integer LINE 1: ...120 2157400,484120 2151990,477250 2151990))',4326) and (055) ^
my start file (local_elem.php) is:

```
     <html>
        <head> 
            <title>selector de elementos GIS</title>    
            <script>
                window.onload=function(){document.forms["cons_elem"].submit();}
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>  
            <?php 
                $foldo=”055”;
                echo '  <form method=POST name="cons_elem" action="/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe">';
                echo "      Generando GIS $foldo";
                echo '      <input name="program" type="hidden" value="/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe">';
                echo '      <input name="map" type="hidden" value="/ms4w/apps/sacmex/local/mapa_b.map">';
                echo '      <input name="mapext" type="hidden" value="shapes">';
                echo '      <input name="qlayer" type="hidden" value="pozos_azc_12">';  
                echo '      <input name="dato" type="hidden" value="May the 4th be with you">'; 
                echo '      <input name="mode" type="hidden" value="ITEMQUERY">';       
                echo '      <input name="qitem" type="hidden" value="n_pozo">';         
                echo "      <input name='qstring' type='hidden' value=$foldo>"; 
                echo '      <input name="dato" type="hidden" value="May the 4th be with you">'; 
                echo '</form>';
            ?>          
    </body>
</html>
```

My mapfile (mapa_b.map) is:

```
    MAP 
    NAME "hola"
    SIZE 500 400
    STATUS ON
    IMAGETYPE png   
    EXTENT 477250 2151990 484120 2157400
    UNITS meters
    WEB
        TEMPLATE "plantilla2.html"
        IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
        IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
    END 
    QUERYMAP
        STATUS ON
        COLOR 242 253 3
        STYLE HILITE
        SIZE 500 400
    END 
    SYMBOLSET "symbols/symbols-pmapper.sym"
    FONTSET "fonts/msfontset.txt"
    SHAPEPATH "../data/"
    Symbol
      Name 'circle'
      Type ELLIPSE
      Filled TRUE
      Points
        1 1
      END
    END 
    # layer pozos posgis    
    LAYER
        NAME "pozos_azc_12"
        CONNECTIONTYPE postgis   
        CONNECTION "user=user password=pass dbname=db host=127.0.0.1 port=80"
        DATA "geom FROM pozos_azc_12 USING UNIQUE gid USING SRID=4326"
        PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
        STATUS DEFAULT
        TYPE point
        TEMPLATE "plantilla2.html"
        METADATA            
            "myvar_validation_pattern" "%qstring%"          
            "DESCRIPTION" "Pozos"
            "RESULT_FIELDS" "n_pozo,profundidad"
            "RESULT_HEADERS" "No.Pozo,Profundidad"              
        END     
        VALIDATION
            'qstring' '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'          
        END     
        CLASS
            Name 'Pozos'
            COLOR 0 0 255
            SYMBOL 'circle'
            SIZE 4
        END     
    END
END
```

And my template file (plantilla2.html) is:

```
    <!– MapServer Template –>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>encuentra</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <form method="GET" action="[program]">
            <strong>Consulta de los datos</strong>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="image" name="img" src="[img]" border="0">
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">                  
                    <p><strong>No.pozo:</strong> [qstring]</p>                  
                    <hr size="1">
                    <p> <strong>Capa:</strong> [qlayer] </p>
                    <p> <strong>X(mapa):</strong> [mapx] </p>
                    <p> <strong>Y(mapa):</strong> [mapy] </p>
                    <p> <strong>Modo:</strong> [mode] </p>
                    <p> <strong>mensaje:</strong> [dato] </p>
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle"><input name="escala" type="image" src="[scalebar]" align="middle" border="0"> 1:[scale]</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
            <input type="hidden" name="map" value="[map]">      
            <input type="hidden" name="imgxy" value="[center]">
            <input type="hidden" name="imgext" value="[mapext]">
            <input type="hidden" name="dato" value="[dato]">
            <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="[mode]">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="qstring" value="[qstring]">          
            <input type="hidden" name="qlayer" value="[qlayer]">            
            <input type="hidden" name="qitem" value="[qitem]">          
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

All looks very simple,  cheking the PostgreSQL logs I find the message complete of the error:

```
2022-01-18 20:16:26 CST ERROR:  el argumento de AND debe ser de tipo boolean, no tipo integer en carácter 720
2022-01-18 20:16:26 CST SENTENCIA:  select "gid","n_pozo”,"profundidad",encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"gid" from pozos_azc_12 where geom && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((477250 2151990,477250 2157400,484120 2157400,484120 2151990,477250 2151990))',4326) and (055)
```

As the error says, the problem is in the AND criteria “and (055)”, i suppose maybe need to be “and (n_pozo=055)”, but I don't know how can I do this, or the itemquery application is wrong.

Does somebody know why PostgreSQL and/or MapServer (MS4W) are not doing the query and not display the map? Or what I'm doing wrong? In essence it has to be very simple ☹

Comment: please include your MS4W version (setenv.bat / mapserv -v).   Also, thanks for using MS4W! :)

Comment: Shure, thanks for your anwer, MS4W v3.0.6, MapServer CGI 6.0.3 postgre 9.1 with posgis

Comment: That is a very old version, please retry with MS4W 4.0.5 from https://ms4w.com and let me know.